# using flex auto calculate the width for inline input fields

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have n number of input fields ranging from 1 to 10, so currently i am doing with `width of 30px`, but i wan't it to automatically calculate and avoid the horizontal scroll

How can i achieve this using flex.

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
    width: 30px;
    height: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="number" class="input " value="">
  <input type="number" class="input " value="">
  <input type="number" class="input " value="">
  <input type="number" class="input " value="">
  <input type="number" class="input " value="">
  <input type="number" class="input " value="">
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `width: 100%` in the `inputs` and it is enough. I leave the example below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 8px;
  margin-top: 24px;
  padding: 0;
}

.input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2rem;
    margin-right: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="number" class="input" value="">
  <input type="number" class="input" value="">
  <input type="number" class="input" value="">
  <input type="number" class="input" value="">
  <input type="number" class="input" value="">
  <input type="number" class="input" value="">
</div>
```

And to leave separation between the elements, you have the option to replace `padding: 0 16px;` by `gap: 8px;`.

The result is the same, but in my opinion the code is much more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change `width:30px` and add `flex-basis:100%;`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-basis.asp